# lightbox recommendation - dont want to resample blowup image

Tags: extensions, javascript, image, gallery

I'm looking for a lightbox type extension that can use the original image for the blow up and that also doesn't require a specific ratio or constraint that defaults for all images.

I'm presently using easy lightbox from template master, but my problem with this, is that they require you specify the max size of the popup image.

I'm using 1.7 and it doesn't have to be free.

Answer (score 2):

I like Swipebox:

http://brutaldesign.github.io/swipebox/#dynamic

It is fast, clean and perfect on mobile too.

Also there is this extention:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/jquery-lightboxes-fancybox-pirobox-etc.html

..which lets you try different Lightboxes within one extention.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/), I have used in some of my projects and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer Shadowbox (shadowbox-js.com). It can handle images, movies, external pages, etc.
You don't have to specify the dimensions of the images in the modal window. Shadowbox will work with Prototype or jQuery.

HTH, Tom

Comment: Call me a cynic but when I see an answer from a user that has just this minute registered and it is promoting a paid for extension when there are loads of excellent free ones available I think `spam`.  Are you the developer of shadowbox-js ?

Comment: Could you please give an example of how this would work? Either code or a link to an example that would help the user evaluate the usefulness of this answer.

Comment: I'm not the developer, I just prefer Shadowbox. And it meets the OP requirements.

Comment: David, add links to js & css in local.xml 
[code]
<action method="addCss"><stylesheet>path/to/shadowbox.css</stylesheet></action>
<action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>path/to/shadowbox.js</name></action>
[/code]
Initialize Shadowbox, by calling Shadowbox.init();

Add <a href="path/to/big-image.jpg "rel="shadowbox"><img src="image.jpg " /></a> to any image you want to show in modal window.

Comment: Feel free to add it to the answer so it is better formatted :)